# extract attachment and upload in azure file share using logic app

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, fileshare

I have created a logic app with trigger " when a new mail arrives at shared mailbox". Now I want to extract the attachment and save it in azure file share.

[image]

In for each I am not able to get attachment id.

Also when instead of get attachment when I directly add action " azure file storage -> create file" I am not getting the name of below details in dynamic content and not even getting folder location

[image]

[image]

also automatically multiple for each loop are coming
[image]

when I selected Attachments below thing happened :-
[image]

****************UPDATE 1****************_

[image]

trigger details :-
[image]

*****update 2*****_____
get attachment is not working it seems
[image]
body:
[image]

Comment: It seems you type `attachem`(which is incorrect) to search in dynamic content. Does this lead to can't find attachment id ?

Comment: i corrected it after that also its only giving attachments and has attachment only @HuryShen

Comment: Could you please check if there is a button "See more" ?

Comment: yes I checked. in that also i am not getting attachment id. is there any other way in which I can upload attachment to azure file share without get attachment action? @HuryShen  (sharing screenshot for see more in the question end)

Comment: It named `Attachments Attachment Id` and it maybe exist at the middle area of the list you provided.

Comment: attachment id came but then thn there are multiple foreach loop automatically. sharing screenshot in the question @HuryShen

Comment: It may be caused by you input `attachments` instead of `Attachments` in the first "For each" loop. Could you please remove all of the connectors/actions in your logic app and add them again ?

Comment: I test it in my side, it doesn't show more foreach loop automatically.

Comment: if u see the screenshot when I am selecting Attachments. it is taking value. But for me its giving multiple loop. i deleted and made a new logic app even after that same thing is happening

Comment: I test it in my side, it works fine when a new email arrives. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWpTA.png) is my logic app screenshot. So I still think the problem was caused by make too many selections and your logic app is messing.

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot of your newly created logic app ?

Comment: yes sure. how do we add screenshot in comment?

Comment: You can add the screenshot in your question as which you did before.

Comment: yes I have updated it please check. again same thing is happening

Comment: You can't add the "Recurrence" as the trigger of your logic app because you already added the "When a new email arrives in a shared mailbox" as trigger. Logic app just allows one trigger in it.

Comment: but I want to run my logic app every day at 10:02 CET , 12:02 , 18 :02 ,20 :02 at these hours

Comment: No, you can just choose one trigger.

Comment: Please provide more details of your trigger requirement, I will try to find if there is a solution for your requirement.

Comment: i want to make a logic app that run every day at 10:02 CET , 12:02 CET,14:02 CET, 18 :02 CET,20 :02 CET.these hours. and scan the shared mail inbox for attachment ( .xls) and upload the the attachment to file share.

Comment: Why do you want the logic app just be triggered at 0:02 CET , 12:02 CET,14:02 CET, 18 :02 CET,20 :02 CET ? Do you mind if the logic app be triggered at any time when a new email arrives?

Comment: but the requirement says it should check mail at these particular time.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can implement this requirement, in my opinion it is difficult to implement. And even though we implement this requirement, the logic app still do same work with be triggered any time. And the cost will not different.

Comment: i think you are right. i will apply subject filter. if we don't apply recurrence trigger and directly use when mail arrive in shared mail box will it work?? i mean I wont get that loop issue??

Comment: I test it in my side and works fine, you can test it in your side again. I will provide my logic app in below area for your reference.

Comment: can you share your logic app and are you able to upload file to file share

Comment: Sorry I forget to test the steps of upload file, I will test it and update my answer later.

Comment: Hi shinu, I have updated my answer.

Comment: how often do you check for item should be 1 day? cause mail will come 5 times in those particular time as I mentioned

Comment: hello @HuryShen I did tried without the recurrence your 1st update with 1min interval and it did not get triggered instead it got skipped. And also I tried again with recurrence and that is still running state from last so many hours. I am totally confused that why it is not working

Comment: @HuryShen i have shared a screenshot in update 2 in my questions. it seems the get attachment (v2) is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarize from the comments, we can't use more than one trigger in logic app. So we can just use "when a new mail arrives at shared mailbox" trigger in it.

Here is my logic app for your reference(I don't configure a shared mailbox, so I use "When a new email arrives" in my logic app):
[image]

Your logic app should be like:
[image]

=================================**Update**==================================

[image]

=================================**Update 2**=================================

[image]

[image]

=================================**Update 3**=================================

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: yes I have done the same as suggested by you. I have also added an action azure file storage->create file . will have to wait till 14:02 Cet to check if it is working successfully

Comment: how often do you check for item should be 1 day? cause mail will come 5 times in those particular time

Comment: @shinu Sorry, what do you mean ? You configure the trigger check every 1 day ? And you want to know how the logic app work if there are 5 emails arrived in last day ?

Comment: As i mentioned those CET timing and every day at those time the mail will arrive. so what should I set how often do you check for item option in when new mail arrive trigger

Comment: @shinu The interval of how often you set for the check depends on your requirement. If you want the attachment be uploaded to file share timely, you can set it with small time interval.

Comment: @shinu If the timeliness requirement is not very high, I suggest you to set the check interval with every 2 hours because the minimum time interval of your time point 10:02 CET , 12:02 CET,14:02 CET, 18 :02 CET,20 :02 CET is 2 hours.

Comment: for now I have set it to 1 min for now. i checked the trigger history, it shows skipped skipped. will it only run and fire when the new mail have actually arrived?

Comment: Yes, if there isn't any email arrived, it will skip until a new email arrive. By the way, if you set it check every minute, it may cost more money for the check operation.

Comment: yes that why i wanted to set these particular timing. if I set 2 hours then it wont on exact those time. the requirement says it should trigger only at 10:02 CET , 12:02 CET,14:02 CET, 18 :02 CET,20 :02 CET  these time but this cant be achieved without recurrence :(

Comment: @shinu Yes, if you set 2 hours, it's difficult for us to let the logic app be trigger at the exact those time. So it depends on your requirement of upload attachment timeliness.

Comment: what should I do then?

Comment: @shinu You still want the logic app be triggered at those time point ? Let me do more test, I will try to find another workaround for your requirement.

Comment: yes. even I am trying from last 2 days. when I am using recurrence same looping thing is happening and without recurrence it will increase the cost and not fulfill the exact requirement

Comment: @shinu Please check the "update 2" of my answer.

Comment: @shinu Note: In "Get emails(v3)" aciton, it can just get unread emails because I set `Fetch Only Unread Messages` with "Yes". So if the emails haven't been marked with "read", they will be fetched again in next logic app execution. And please pay attention to the `Top` field of "Get emails(v3)" action, I guess there is a limit of the `Top` value but I don't know what the limit is.

Comment: @shinu If still have any problem, you can add comments here and I will try to help you tomorrow because it's time for off work.

Comment: i have to use shared mail box as the email address where there mail come is shared one not the normal email.

Comment: hello @huryshen I did tried without the recurrence your 1st update with 1min interval and it did not get triggered instead it got skipped.  And also I tried again with recurrence and that is still running state from last so many hours. I am totally confused that why it is not working

Comment: @shinu I don't know why your logic app wasn't triggered. I provided my logic app in "Update 3", it works fine in my side.

Comment: were u able to upload the file to file share?

Comment: @shinu Yes, I test with add the "create file" action just now, it upload the attachments to my file storage success.

Comment: I added a screenshot under update in my question. is your logic app arrangement same as mine?? I don't know why it is not working from my side. its only skipping.

Comment: @shinu Since you mentioned your trigger skipped, so please show the details of the trigger in your screenshot.

Comment: I haven updated the screenshot under trigger details.

Comment: @shinu As you enabled "Only with attachments" and also use "Subject Filter", please check if the received email contains attachments and also check if the email match the filter.

Comment: yes i checked. the emails with attachment are received and also the subject filter is correct

Comment: even i sent a mail just now and logic app still did not got triggered

Comment: i have shared a screenshot in update 2 in my questions. it seems the get attachment (v2) is not working.

Comment: @shinu Did you configure your "Get attachment" action same with mine in "Update 3" of my answer ?

Comment: @shinu It seems the number of attachments in email is 0, so the "for each" didn't loop. Please go to the run history page which you provided in "Update 2" and click the trigger, and check the "Body" of the trigger. Check if there is any attachments in the "Body" json data.

Comment: i removed the get attachment and simply tried to send mail to myself using For each. even that is not working.  there is tick beside foreach but not beside the mail. now I am confused its either for each issue or what

Comment: @shinu Please check if there is any attatchments in the "Body" json of the trigger as I mentioned in previous comment. Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTkPt.png)

Comment: in body its  "attachments": [],. i have updated the screenshot too.  what should be done in this case? i am sending attachment with the mail.

Comment: @shinu So the problem is the trigger didn't get the attachments of your email. You need to do two things: 1. Check if the email contains any attachments. 2. How did you added the attachments into the email when you send it ?

Comment: yes the email contain attachment i just checked the sent items and I added attachment like normally we do in compose email using that attach option ( pin icon)

Comment: @shinu I add the attachments by click "Attach File" in outlook, did you do same with me ? And by the way, did you enable "Include Attachments" in your trigger(even though I notice you have enabled it from your screenshot, but please double check) ?

Comment: it worked. it finally worked. i uploaded the attachment like you are doing "attach file" and I am able to upload the file to fileshare

Comment: Thankyou so so much @Huryshen. I am really grateful to you for your help and time :)